# How to add a slide effect to removeClass jQuery

Tags: jquery, tabs, slide, removeclass

I have been trying to find the answer to my problem on Google for days now without any luck so I was hoping somebody here could help.

The code can be found at this link http://www.scriptbreaker.com/javascript/script/JQuery-vertical-tab-menu, it is just a vertical tab menu and I have already made it change on click not hover.

What I want is the content to slide up and the new content slide down (depending on which tab was clicked as to whether it goes up or down if that makes sense) when it is clicked.

This is the jQuery for it:

```
<script language="JavaScript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $(".tabs .tab[id^=tab_menu]").click(function() {
                var curMenu=$(this);
                $(".tabs .tab[id^=tab_menu]").removeClass("selected")
                curMenu.addClass("selected")

                var index=curMenu.attr("id").split("tab_menu_")[1];
                $(".curvedContainer .tabcontent").css("display","none")
                $(".curvedContainer #tab_content_"+index).css("display","block")
            });
        });
    </script>
```

**Update**
Here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/swift29/4pVtB/

Thanks in advance, Swift.

Comment: _What I want is the content to slide up and the new content slide down (depending on which tab was clicked as to whether it goes up or down if that makes sense)_ No it does not make sense. Please elaborate.

Comment: got a jsfiddle to show as demo?

Comment: it does make sense can u add your css and the code to fiddle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/4pVtB/5/) will suffice you. You need simply call a `.slideup/slideDown` methods instead of simply using `display:block/none`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".tabs .tab[id^=tab_menu]").click(function() {
    var curMenu=$(this);
    $(".tabs .tab[id^=tab_menu]").removeClass("selected");
    curMenu.addClass("selected");

    var index=curMenu.attr("id").split("tab_menu_")[1];
    $(".curvedContainer .tabcontent").slideUp('fast');
    $(".curvedContainer #tab_content_"+index).slideDown('fast');
});
});​
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I can't believe I didn't think of that. Is it possible to make the old and new slide together rather than the new one overlaping the last?

Comment: @swift29, if I understood you right, all jQuery animations afaik are executed asynchronously, they are not depend on each other. Does it work for you?

Comment: I mean kind of like a carousel style instead of the overlapping, it doesn't matter though I was just curious.

Answer (score 0):

one lil mod: http://jsfiddle.net/4pVtB/7/

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".tabs .tab[id^=tab_menu]").click(function() {
        var curMenu = $(this);
        var cur_index=curMenu.attr("id").split("tab_menu_")[1];
        var old_index=$(".tabs .selected").attr("id").split("tab_menu_")[1];
        if (cur_index==old_index) {
            return;
        }
        $(".tabs .tab[id^=tab_menu]").removeClass("selected");
        curMenu.addClass("selected");
        $("#tab_content_"+old_index).slideUp('slow');
        $("#tab_content_"+cur_index).slideDown('slow');
    });
});
```